# How to disable button once clicked in iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I have made a footer with 5 buttons, I want to disable the button once clicked till another button is clicked (means once another button is clicked then button should be re enable it). I am posting my code.

**code**

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger index= btn.tag;
[self setNavigationBarButtons:index];

switch (btn.tag)
{
    case 1: // all media type
    {  btn.enable=No;
        messageToBeEdit =nil;

    }
        break;
    case 2: // image type
    { btn.enable=No;
        messageToBeEdit = nil;

    }
        break;
    case 3: // video type
    { btn.enable=No;
        messageToBeEdit = nil;

    }
        break;
    case 4: // text type
    { btn.enable=No;
        //  forth button

        break;
    }
        break;
    case 5: // audio type
    {//fifth button
        btn.enable=No;
        messageToBeEdit = nil;
    }
        break;
```

My issue is I can't able to click once i have clicked it, I want to reenable it once another button is clicked.

Comment: you can do that with UISegmentedControl

Comment: @ Concentrated H2SO4 have a look at http://www.makemegeek.com/uisegmentedcontrol-example-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) tapButton:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger index= btn.tag;
    [self setNavigationBarButtons:index]

    //first enable all the other buttons
    for(UIButton *b in [[btn superview] subviews]) {
        if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
             b.enabled = YES; //reenable 
        }
    }

    btn.enabled = NO; //then disable tapped button
}
```

You don't need `switch` case here, as you're already getting tapped button.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `b.enabled`

Comment: @UditS, thanks for the correction, you're right. It should be, `enabled` and not `enable`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep references of All the buttons, (eg Button1, Button2.. etc)

In your switch case, enable all other buttons. For instance, if user tapped on Button1, then enable all other buttons like

```
button2.enabled = YES;
button3.enabled = YES;
button4.enabled = YES;
button5.enabled = YES;
```

A better approach would be to keep **IBOutletCollection** of all the buttons and loop through the array to enable all other buttons.

Comment: Tags are fine but to disable a button you need to have it's reference. Tag will not help you there.

Comment: `IBOutletCollection` is a good option to make this approach done. +1